# Securing the keystore key?

Tags: certificates, key-management

My program, is installed on specific computers that use a shared, common login. The program decrypts variously sized (1KB-1GB) data assets which were encrypted elsewhere, and transferred over. Each asset is encrypted using a uniquely generated symmetrical AES256 key. (Best practice is to not reuse keys, right???)

Key / AssetId pairs then get stored in an encrypted "keystore". (As far as I can tell, this could be anything from a database to json/xml/txt blob that's on, or accessible by the 'authorized' computer.)

I've started looking into using a non-exportable SHA256, RSA, DataEncipherment, DocumentEncryption certificate as the keystore's key but don't quite know if that's a valid approach, how to achieve it yet, or what specific certificate extension OID's are needed.

I've also read about using RSA encryption on the AES keystore key, and sticking the result somewhere in the registry. The RSA private key is from a x509 certificate that's deployed to target platforms manually by the admin. (Seems like a game of find the sausage, mixed with the already mentioned non-exportable certificate.)

The question **Where/how do I store the keystore decryption key?** comes up a whole lot when searching with many server/cloud-based 'solutions'. I'm just not able to determine whether my interpretation of the available information is actually secure, or even correct for my use case.

Comment: If your private key is from an x509 certificate, why not leave it there? Store the cert in your cert store and grant access to the private key to your application's service account. There are already plenty of measures in place to protect your cert store.

Comment: My understanding here is limited, but wouldn't access to the private key in the decryption certificate require some password itself? Or is merely having the certificate installed 'the password'?

Comment: If we are talking about Windows, access to the key is controlled by active directory account and/or group membership.